# Can't restart MariaDB after adding datadir line to my.cnf file

Tags: opensuse, mysql, mariadb

Having a issue getting MariaDB to restart after adding the following line to the [mysqld] section of my.cnf:

```
datadir = /home/mysql
```

It won't restart. Could this be a permissions issue. This is the directory that holds all my SQL data. Here is what systemctl status mysql.service shows

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-11-10 08:33:00 CST; 36s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 14438 ExecStart=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 14425 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14412 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/mysql/mysql-systemd-helper install (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14438 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[14438]: 2021-11-10  8:33:00 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.17-MariaDB-log) starting as process 14438 ...
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[14438]: 2021-11-10  8:33:00 0 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 32214)
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[14438]: 2021-11-10  8:33:00 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 151 (was 151)  table_cache: 421 (was 2000)
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[14438]: 2021-11-10  8:33:00 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql/law-amp3.lower-test
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[14438]: [87B blob data]
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 mysql-systemd-helper[14438]: 2021-11-10  8:33:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 10 08:33:00 law-amp3 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a permissions issue. Make sure that the owner of the directory is mysql. For example

```
chown --reference=/var/lib/mysql /home/mysql
chmod --reference=/var/lib/mysql /new/dir/for/mysql
```

Edit:

See if the service file has ProtectHome

```
vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service
```

Change ProtectHome=true to ProtectHome=**false**

Save the file

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart mariadb

Comment: The following is a directory listing showing that /home/mysql is owned by the mysql users and group

law-amp3:/home # dir
total 36
drwx------  2 root         root  16384 Oct  8  2019 lost+found
drwxr-x---  7 mysql        mysql  4096 Nov 10 08:28 mysql

Comment: Please see my edited answer